# Secuence updates optimize parallel container

Tags: sql, ssis

I have numerous secuence container that perform updates to the same table. To run in series, the process is right but takes a long time , as I can optimize the whole project in general, to execute these tasks in parallel and optimize time , since error execute SSIS presents parallel ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I suspect that trying to perform a bunch of updates to the same table at the same time will not improve performance due to the resulting blocking, but the best way to find out is to test.

Comment: Right now I have the whole series flow . If I modified in parallel, has DAOD error can not perform simultaneous updates in SSIS

Comment: Stage all of your changes to a heap. Once all the the parallel operations are complete, then use that staged table to perform a mass update.